# Broken PHP if-elseif statement

Tags: php, mysql, sql, if-statement, session

I am working on a personal project and I'm trying to create a php script to display a follow button if the logged in session user doesn't already follow the user displayed..

Heres what I've got:

```
<?php
      $query = query("SELECT*FROM following, users WHERE followed_id=" .escape_string($_GET['id'])." 
      AND user_id=".escape_string($_GET['id'])." AND follower_id =".escape_string($_SESSION['user_id'])."");
      confirm($query);
      while($row = fetch_array($query)):

       if(mysqli_num_rows($query)==0){

         $followbutton=<<<DELIMITER

       <form method="post" action="">
         <input type="hidden" name="followed" value="{$row['user_id']}">
         <input type="hidden" name="follower" value="{$_SESSION['user_id']}">
         <input class="btn btn-info" type="submit" name="submit" value="follow">
       </form>

DELIMITER;
       echo $followbutton;

    }elseif($row['follower_id'] == $_SESSION['user_id']){
      $unfollowbutton=<<<DELIMITER

    <form method="post" action="unfollow.php?id={$row['user_id']}">
      <input class="btn btn-info" type="submit"  value="Unfollow">
    </form>

DELIMITER;
    echo $unfollowbutton;

  }
endwhile;    ?>
```

Here's what query, escape_string, fetch_array and confirm do:

```
function redirect($location){
header("Location: $location");
}

function query ($sql){
global $connection;
return mysqli_query($connection,$sql);
}

function confirm($result) {
global $connection;
if(!$result){
    die("QUERY FAILED ".mysqli_error($connection));
}
}

function escape_string($string){
global $connection;
return mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$string);
 }

 function fetch_array($result) {
return mysqli_fetch_array($result);
}
```

The "following" table only has two columns; followed_id and follower_id. When the user clicks the follow button it passes the logged in user_id as the follower_id and the user_id for the person being followed as the followed_id. Since there wont be any entries if user A hasn't already followed user B I need the button to display only if no results are returned from the query.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please edit your question to specify exactly what's not working with a _minimal example_ (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example for reference). Is there a bug in what you currently have, or are you wondering how to achieve some specific functionality? Is there actually a conditional not working as expected, or does this issue have something to do with outputting/submitting a form, connecting to the database, etc.

Comment: Error reporting/logs show what, in regards to possible errors? What isn't working the way you want it to?

Comment: Remove the double quotes in AND follower_id =".escape_string($_SESSION['user_id'])."") at the end

Comment: also, try to put space after `SELECT` in `SELECT*FROM following`

Comment: There aren't any errors I just can't get it to function the way I want it to. If user A is following user B the 'unfollow' button displays properly on user B's profile. However I also want the 'follow' button to display instead if there aren't any results returned from the sql query.

Comment: Assuming that query should ever only return 1 or 0 rows, I'd remove the `while` and just get the row. Additionally, if you inspect (via breakpoint debugging or `error_log` outputs) the values of `$row['follower_id']` and `$_SESSION['user_id']` that will likely point you in the right direction.

Comment: `However I also want the 'follow' button to display instead if there aren't any results returned from the sql query.` Change your `elseif` to a regular `else`. Currently, you`ll only go into your elseif, if a row is returned.

Comment: Note: The [object-oriented interface to `mysqli`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.connections.php) is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface where missing a single `i` can cause trouble. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is largely an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: Using HEREDOC style inlining with throw-away variables is a really messy way of outputting plain HTML. Remember in PHP you can drop back to echo mode by closing it `?> ...HTML... <?php`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you either want to display a *follow* button or an *unfollow* button. In that case, you can use a simple if/else statement. <strike>Currently, your elseif statement will only be true when a row is returned because you're checking for its existence: `if ($row['follower_id'] == $_SESSION['user_id'])`.</strike> *I now see that your `elseif` is checking if the user exists. I had it backwards. Everything else in my answer still stands.*

For what's it is worth, you really should be using prepared statements to prevent SQL injection attacks. Also, I think your code could be simplified a bit to make it clearer.

- Not sure why you're selecting from both the `following` and `users` ables. You only need to check if the `following` table has you (the logged in user) and the person you're checking against, no?
- No need for that `while` loop. You can simply count the rows. If there are > 0 rows, you know that you're following the person already. In theory I guess, there should only be 1 row.

Here's an example of how I'd write this. I'm using `PDO` here simply because that's my go to API, but you can continue to use `mysqli`.

```
<?php
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT count(*) FROM following WHERE follower_id = ? AND followed_id = ?");
$stmt->execute([
    $_SESSION['user_id'], // logged-in user
    $_GET['id']           // who we are following
]);

// How to count when using PDO - https://phpdelusions.net/pdo_examples/count
$count = $stmt->fetchColumn();

if ($count > 0) {
    // show `unfollow` form
} else {
    // show `follow` form
}
```

Comment: Wooooooow my dude. This worked a treat and I'm going to switch to using prepared statements. 
A+ explanation of where I was going wrong too. What a guy!